# MS SQL Server Suggestion required

Tags: sql-server-2014

I need to find out the distinct entries in a table - order by the last transaction date in that table.

Here is the script to create the table and populate it with values

```
CREATE TABLE SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ID] [int] IDENTITY(100000001,1) NOT NULL,
[ProductNo] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Container] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[QtyOnHand] [decimal]
)

INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0001',
 'Contr0001',
 '8000'     
 )
INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0001',
 'Contr0001',
 '7990'     
 )
INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0001',
 'Contr0001',
 '7988'     
 )
INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0002',
 'Contr0002',
 '5000'     
 )
INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0002',
 'Contr0002',
 '4999'     
 )
INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0002',
 'Contr0002',
 '4995'     
 )
INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0003',
 'Contr0003',
 '3000'     
 )
INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0003',
 'Contr0003',
 '2999'     
 )
INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0001',
 'Contr0001',
 '7984'     
 )

 INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0001',
 'Contr0001',
 '7982'     
 )
INSERT INTO SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
([ProductNo],
[Container] ,
[QtyOnHand] )
VALUES
(
 'PRd0003',
 'Contr0003',
 '2996'     
 )
```

The result I would need is like the following  -
1   PRd0002
2   PRd0001
3   PRd0003

I tried the following

```
Select DISTINCT ProductNo  from SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY Order by ID
```

But I get the error -

> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 122 ORDER BY items must appear in the
>   select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Not sure how to approach this. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot order by something that is not included in your select statement while using distinct. If you remove the order by, you get your 3 rows as expected. You could then order them by the productno if you wanted.

```
 Select DISTINCT ProductNo  
 from #SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
```

or

```
 Select DISTINCT ProductNo  
 from #SM_TRANSACTION_HISTORY 
 Order by ProductNo
```

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this result with SQL?